# Android Canvas How to achieve Continous Smooth Motion(Rotation)

Tags: android, animation, canvas

My problem is, i am trying to rotate  a canvas around a certain point smoothly and continously. The problem is, it does not look smooth. Here is my code below;

```
 rotateRunnable.run();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    rect.set(xLeft, yTop, xRight, yBottom);
    paint.setColor(color);
    if(rotate)
        canvas.rotate(rotateAngle,CoordinateUtils.centerX,CoordinateUtils.centerY);
    canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);

}

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable rotateRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if(rotateReverse)
            rotateAngle = rotateAngle - DValues.markerSpeed;
        else
            rotateAngle = rotateAngle + DValues.markerSpeed;
        postInvalidate(); //will trigger the onDraw
        handler.postDelayed(this,1); //
}};
```

*Is it good idea to translate views in thread? How to achieve continous smooth motion? Also where should i check collision detection with another view object? OnDraw or somewhere else?*

Comment: I think the issue is you're calling the `Handler` every 1 millisecond, so you're just calling this method constantly. Instead, since the logic is very simple and easy, it may better to move it to the `onDraw()` method.  Then call `invalidate()` on the View.  Then, all the calculations will be done every draw cycle.

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually all i am calling is invalidate method of Viewi nothing more. Can you show an example?

Comment: Also, where should i check for collision detection? OnDraw or ..?

Comment: I think that can be put in onDraw.  Depends on how complicated the calculations are.  If you're trying to make a game engine of some kind, then that's a whole different topic than simple animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're calling the Handler every 1 millisecond, so you're just calling this method constantly. Instead, since the logic is very simple and easy, it may better to move it to the onDraw() method. Then call invalidate() on the View. Then, all the calculations will be done every draw cycle.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(rotateReverse)
       rotate = rotate - DValues.markerSpeed;
    else
       rotate = rotate + DValues.markerSpeed;

    rect.set(xLeft, yTop, xRight, yBottom);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.rotate(rotate,CoordinateUtils.centerX,CoordinateUtils.centerY);
    canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);

    invalidate(); //will trigger the onDraw
}
```

So this will tell the system to perform another draw to update the `View`. It will only call `invalidate()` on draw cycles. If the phone is still drawing at 60 fps, then the rotate will be called 60 times a second, so you may need to adjust the speed (possibly base it off the pixel density of the phone). You will also need to base the rotate distance based on where it should be based off how long it was since the last draw cycle (in case the UI froze).

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way does calling invalidate in every draw affect performance badly? Should postInvalidate or invalidate?

Comment: It will cause more battery drain and take more resources compared to a static view that never changes, but anything with continuing animations will be redrawing constantly.

Comment: `postInvalidate()` just lets you call `invalidat()` from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Is there a better performanceful way to rotate a View? I wanna learn best possible way.

Comment: I don't think so. Not without using a graphics engine. You can also look in to `ObjectAnimators` as well as they are far easier to work with (very little performance hit). Though it will be more cumbersome to do collision detection which you said is one of your requirements.

Comment: My problem is , since i am using canvas.rotate(), it does not give me exact coordinates of where it rotated the object. How can i get canvas locations? Because when i set Rect, i dont touch it anymore it just rotates. How can i get coordinates?